# How to count the rows in a table with Coded UI

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

I am trying to count the number of Rows in the WinTable that is dynamically generated by our application. I was hoping that it would be as simple as using the code below, but the first two 'count's return 0. The 3rd returns 3, even though there is 50+ rows generated. Maybe that count is Table Header, Table Rows and something else?

```
WinTable OrderTable = UIApp.UIItemWindow.UIItemTable;
int count1 = OrderTable.Rows.Count();
int count2 = OrderTable.Rows.Count;
UITestControlCollection temp = OrderTable.GetChildren();
var count3 = temp.Count();
Console.WriteLine("Number of Rows: {0}, {1}, {2}", count1, count2, count3);

Output:
Number of Rows: 0,0,3
```

In anycase, is there a way to count the rows in a WinTable through Coded UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered there is another level within the WinTable object.

```
WinClient OrderRows= UIApp.UIItemWindow.UIItemTable.UIDataPanelClient;
UITestControlCollection count = OrderRows.GetChildren();
var a = count.Count;
Console.WriteLine("Number of Rows: {0}", count);

Output: 
Number of Rows: 456
```

This looks closer to the correct value.

Comment: Isn't that possible to take it as a WinTable and count the rows?. Did you try it?

Comment: The above works. I had to wait 2 days before I could tick my own answer.